# Why do I get "associated type not allowed here" error when implementing Iterator?

Tags: generics, rust, iterator

I'd like to convert an iterator to a new iterator which yields every-other element, i.e. only the even indexed elements. Here's an attempt:

```
struct EvenIter<T, I: Iterator<Item = T>> {
    inner: I
}

impl<I, T> Iterator<Item = T> for EvenIter<T, I> {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        let temp = self.inner.next();
        let _ = self.inner.next();
        temp
    }
}

pub fn evens<T>(iter: impl Iterator<Item = T>) -> impl Iterator<Item = T> {
    EvenIter { inner: iter }
}
```

The `impl` line is wrong with error message

```
error[E0229]: associated type bindings are not allowed here
 --> src/lib.rs:5:21
  |
5 | impl<I, T> Iterator<Item = T> for EvenIter<T, I> {
  |                     ^^^^^^^^ associated type not allowed here
```

Another attempt has exactly the same compiler error at exactly the same place:

```
struct EvenIter<T> {
    inner: dyn Iterator<Item = T>
}

impl<T> Iterator<Item = T> for EvenIter<T> {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        let temp = self.inner.next();
        let _ = self.inner.next();
        temp
    }
}

pub fn evens<T>(iter: impl Iterator<Item = T>) -> impl Iterator<Item = T> {
    EvenIter { inner: iter }
}
```

How do we explain what we want to the compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax for associated items is to put them inside the `impl` block:

```rust
struct EvenIter<T, I: Iterator<Item = T>> {
    inner: I
}

impl<I: Iterator<Item = T>, T> Iterator for EvenIter<T, I> {
    type Item = T; // <-- here
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        let temp = self.inner.next();
        let _ = self.inner.next();
        temp
    }
}

pub fn evens<T>(iter: impl Iterator<Item = T>) -> impl Iterator<Item = T> {
    EvenIter { inner: iter }
}

fn main() {
    evens((0..10).into_iter()).for_each(|x| println!("{x}"));
}
```

Also, another constraint was required on `I` in the impl, stating that `I: Iterator<Item = T>`.

Comment: You don't need the extra constraint if you remove `T` and use `I::Item` to refer to the item type ([demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=75dcc0a4b850801827346ebe38ff7b14))

Comment: Why is that `type Item = T;` line needed since we already put that constraint in the `impl` line?

Comment: Because that's describing `I` not the `impl` for `EventIter` and that's the syntax for associated types.